# Формирование вывода секунды в time.clock()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как правильно формировать корректный вывод секунд в `time.clock()`?

```
import time
li = [9, 2, 7, 6, 0, 5, 8, 4]
n = 1
sturt_time = time.clock()
while n < len(li):
     for i in range(len(li)-n):
          if li[i] > li[i+1]:
               li[i],li[i+1] = li[i+1],li[i]
     n += 1
print(li)
print (time.clock() - sturt_time, 'second')
```

Программа выводит:

> [0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>   8.699336748881915e-05 second

Comment: `"{:g} seconds".format(time.clock() - sturt_time)` за подробностями смотри доки на `format()`.

Comment: В третьей ветке же можно и так: f'{variable} second'

Comment: в сторону:вместо time.clock,  [используйте timeit.default_timer для переносимости](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы напечатать измеренное время в удобной для людей форме,  сократив число показываемых цифр и используя явные приставки (micro-, milli-):

```
def human_seconds(seconds, fmt="%.3g %s"):
    """Return human-readable string that represents given seconds."""
    t = 1e6 * seconds # start with µsec
    for suff in "usec msec".split():
        if t < 1000:
            return fmt % (t, suff)
        t /= 1000
    return fmt % (t, "sec")
```

Пример:

```
print(human_seconds(8.699336748881915e-05))
# -> 87 usec
```

Пример использования для сравнения производительности: [`reporttime.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/4276624#file-reporttime-py-L37) использует `human_seconds()` для вывода результатов: [Как можно засечь время выполнения каждой из функций и суммарное время выполнения программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775750/23044).

Comment: Так только читать сложнее будет...

Comment: @Qwertiy: вы серьёзно думаете, что `8.699336748881915e-05 second` более предпочтительно, чем `87 usec`? 1- один вариант печатает просто шум (цифры, которые ничего не значат -- в пределах ошибки измерения) 2- для сравнения производительности (результаты в пределах пары-порядков как правило), удобно когда одни и те же единицы используются (`timeit` из стандартной библиотеки использует эти единицы). Посмотрите на таблицу с результатами по ссылке.

Comment: Я думаю, что надо всегда выводить целое число в миллисекундах, а не подгонять единицу измерения. А микро - это вообще за пределами точности.

Comment: @Qwertiy: обычно, важны только пару цифр и важна *относительная* производительность, поэтому вариант, который только 2-3 цифры выводит более предпочтительный, нежели вариант, где нули приходится считать (ошибка может в наносекундах измеряться, результат может целые секунды занимать -- если использовать только миллисекунды, то много цифр будет: [пример](https://gist.github.com/zed/a66866c01beab98ce1228138b4c439f4)).

Comment: Наносекунды - это за пределами точности измерений. а вот сравнивать `999 msec` и `1.2 sec` - неудобно. У всего вывода должна быть одна единица измерения (возможно, подобранная под задачу, но по умолчанию - мс) и значение должно быть целым.

Comment: @Qwertiy: вы бы хотя бы на ссылку нажали с примером, в котором явно показано что ошибка в наносекундах измеряется (модуль perf внутри я думаю используется). Я вам реальный пример показываю, не специально созданный для дискуссии. Пример сравнивает производительность двух вариантов реализации одной и той же функции. Пример, всего одна страница (экран), достаточно только на вывод посмотреть ~дюжины строк и всё.

Comment: Во-первых, мне там уже неудобно смотреть табличку, потому что вместо выровненных чисел приходится проверять единицу измерения. Во-вторых, все утилиты для замера давно научились повторять замер несколько раз, а выводить время исполнения одной итерации. В случае же с самостоятельным замером времени результат должен быть адекватного порядка, а не наносекунды.

Comment: @Qwertiy: не путаете величину, которую меряют и соответствующую ошибку. К примеру (из обсуждаемой ссылки, даже кликать не надо):  `3.44 µs ± 34.5 ns` (здесь: 3.44 микросекунды это величина, а 34.5 **наносекунды** это ошибка) Можете это в миллисекунды превратить и посмотреть как выглядит. Как я сказал, вероятно `perf` модуль используется для измерения. Про "адекватные" порядки не нужно говорить (вы неявно оскорбляете автора perf модуля. Я не вполне согласен с [его методами измерений](https://goo.gl/Abnajy), но во всех моих случаях они дают сравнимые результаты, с методами, которые я предпочитаю

Comment: Я вообще ничего не говорил про perf-модуль. Но там целый модуль, который что-то замеряет и что-то считает по этим замерам. Почему ты считаешь, что его идеи применимы к обычным замерам через time?

Comment: @Qwertiy: я не знаю намерено вы не понимаете (иногда это называют "дурика включить") или я так совсем непонятно объясняю, но обсуждение, когда приходится объяснять, что я уже дважды упоминал в последних двух подряд идущих комментариях,  я не вижу смысла продолжать. Выполните поиск по странице по слову `perf` -- если вам так и не будет ясна связь между perf и *"результат должен быть адекватного порядка, а не наносекунды"*, то пусть это загадкой для вас останется.

Comment: То, что для perf наносекунды - это нормальный порядок, не означает, что в замере на коленках через time. Или я опять чего-то не понимаю?