# Как можно засечь время выполнения каждой из функций и суммарное время выполнения программы

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, производительность

Есть код с тремя сотрировками, есть отчет о времени выполнения программы.
Как можно засечь время выполнения каждой из функций и суммарное время выполнения программы.
Еще, если не сложно, посоветуйте как сократить программу.

```
import numpy
import time
start_time = time.clock()
def selection(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort
    for i in range(len(a)):
        idxMin = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
            if a[j] < a[idxMin]:
                idxMin = j
        tmp = a[idxMin]
        a[idxMin] = a[i]
        a[i] = tmp
    return a

def insertion(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort
    for i in range(len(a)):
        v = a[i]
        j = i
        while (a[j-1] > v) and (j > 0):
            a[j] = a[j-1]
            j = j - 1
        a[j] = v
    return a

def bubble(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort
    for i in range(len(a),0,-1):
        for j in range(1, i):
            if a[j-1] > a[j]:
                tmp = a[j-1]
                a[j-1] = a[j]
                a[j] = tmp
    return a

ary = numpy.random.choice(100000, 100000, replace=False)
print (len(ary), ary[:5])
print (len(selection(ary)), selection(ary)[:5])
print (len(insertion(ary)), insertion(ary)[:5])
print (len(bubble(ary)), bubble(ary)[:5])
print ("{:g} s".format(time.clock() - start_time))
```

Comment: [Примеры...](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#examples) У вас задача чисто академическая?

Comment: @MaxU Отчеты о времени каждой функции - это задание. А уменьшение кода программы чисто мой интерес..

Comment: лучше отдельно задавать вопросы *"Как можно засечь время выполнения каждой из функций и суммарное время выполнения программы."* и *"как сократить программу"* для второго вопроса можно [tag:code-review] метку выставить (прочтите [описание метки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0/info) и посмотрите примеры существующих вопрос, чтобы убедиться  чего ожидать и подходит ли это в вашем случае)

Comment: related: [Compare sorting algorithms' performance](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Compare_sorting_algorithms%27_performance#Python)

Comment: стоит упомянуть: 1- `a = arrayToSort` не копирует `arrayToSort` поэтому ваши функции изменяют ввод по месту. В таких случаях в Питоне принято, чтобы функции ничего не возвращали (сравните `L.sort()` и `sorted(L)` -- последнее не изменяет `L`, поэтому `sorted()` возвращает значение. 2- поэлементный невекторизованный доступ к numpy массивам крайне медленный. В вашем случае даже обычные Питон списки вероятно были бы быстрее. 3- `numpy.random.choice(100000, 100000, replace=False)` можно на просто `numpy.random.permutation(100000)` заменить (тот же результат, но более ясно и вероятно эффективно).

Answer (score 11):

Чтобы измерить время выполнения программы, можно `time` команду использовать (часто встроена в shell):

```
$ time python -c 'import time; time.sleep(1)'
python -c 'import time; time.sleep(1)'  0.01s user 0.00s system 1% cpu 1.021 total
```

Если команда недоступна, её [можно реализовать в Питоне](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28520489/4279).

Чтобы посмотреть сколько времени индивидуальные функции занимают, можно [`cProfile` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#instant-user-s-manual) использовать:

```
$ python -m cProfile -s time your_module.py
```

В графическом виде результаты удобно в [KCachegrind](https://kcachegrind.github.io/html/CallGraph.html) просматривать. [Пример команд](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561512/4279). Больше вариантов: [How can you profile a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/582336/4279)

[`line_profiler`](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler#line-profiler) позволяет построчно сравнение производить.

**Содержание:**

- timeit
- reporttime.py
- make-figures.py
- reporttime + pandas

## timeit

Чтобы измерить производительность отдельной функции, можно [`timeit` модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) использовать:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'from insertion_sort import sorted; L = list(range(10**5))' 'sorted(L)'
```

Тот же интерфейс предоставляет [`pyperf` модуль](https://pyperf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/run_benchmark.html) (помимо прочего):

```
$ python -m pyperf timeit -s '...' 'sorted(L)'
```

Документация утверждает, что [`pyperf` более надёжные результаты выдаёт](http://pyperf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli.html#timeit-versus-perf-timeit).

Для интерактивной работы можно `%timeit` magic в [ipython](https://ipython.org/)/[jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/)  использовать.

## reporttime.py

Оптимизируя выполнение функции, стоит убедиться что она работает корректно (тесты), что изменения действительно ускорили её работу (сравнение производительности). Для этого [можно `pytest-benchmark`использовать](http://pytest-benchmark.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Для удобства сравнения производительности нескольких алгоритмов, можно автоматически соответствующие функции собрать по общему префиксу в имени ([`get_functions_with_prefix()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/4276624#file-reporttime-py-L77)). К примеру, если функции в вопросе можно назвать: `sorted_selection`, `sorted_insertion`, `sorted_bubble` и поместить в `daedra.py` файл:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
from reporttime import get_functions_with_prefix, measure
import daedra

funcs = get_functions_with_prefix('sorted_', module=daedra)
for comment, L in [
        ("all same", [1] * 10**3),
        ("range", list(range(10**3))),
        ("random", list(range(10**3)))]:
    if comment == "random":
        random.shuffle(L)
    measure(funcs, args=[L], comment=comment)
```

где [`reporttime.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/4276624#file-reporttime-py). `measure()` функция измеряет производительность функций похожим на `python -mtimeit` команду способом.

#### Результаты

```
name                  time  ratio comment
sorted_insertion  184 usec   1.00 all same
sorted_selection 55.9 msec 303.86 all same
sorted_bubble    59.4 msec 322.92 all same
name                  time  ratio comment
sorted_insertion  186 usec   1.00 range
sorted_selection 57.7 msec 309.44 range
sorted_bubble    60.8 msec 326.40 range
name                  time ratio comment
sorted_selection   58 msec  1.00 random
sorted_insertion 66.2 msec  1.14 random
sorted_bubble     119 msec  2.05 random
```

Таблица показывает, что на уже отсортированном вводе `sorted_insertion()` функция заметно выигрывает (в этом случае линейное время для этой функции требуется по сравнению с квадратичным для `sorted_selection()` и `sorted_bubble()`). Для случайного ввода, производительность примерно одинаковая. `sorted_bubble()` хуже во всех вариантах.

## make-figures.py

В качестве альтернативы можно декоратор использовать такой как [`@to_compare`](https://gist.github.com/zed/235395#file-main-py-L14), чтобы собрать функции для сравнения и адаптировать их для [`make-figures.py` скрипта](https://gist.github.com/zed/235404), который измеряет производительность и строит графики. [Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1737862/4279).

Чтобы нарисовать время выполнения функций для разных вводов:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#file: plot_daedra.py
import random

def seq_range(n):
    return list(range(n))

def seq_random(n):
    L = seq_range(n)
    random.shuffle(L)
    return L

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from subprocess import check_call

    import daedra
    from reporttime import get_functions_with_prefix

    # measure performance and plot it
    check_call(["make-figures.py"] + [
        "--sort-function=daedra." + f.__name__
        for f in get_functions_with_prefix('sorted_', module=daedra)
    ] + [
        "--sequence-creator=plot_daedra." + f.__name__
        for f in get_functions_with_prefix('seq_')
    ] + sys.argv[1:])
```

`seq_range()`, `seq_random()` задают два типа ввода (уже отсортированный и случайный соответственно). Можно определить дополнительные типы, определив `seq_*(n)` функцию. Пример запуска:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=. python plot_daedra.py --maxn 1024
```

`PYTHONPATH=.` используется, чтобы [`make-figures.py`](https://gist.github.com/zed/235404) смог найти `plot_daedra` модуль (с `seq_range`, `seq_random` функциями) в текущей директории. `--maxn` определяет наибольшее `n`, которое в `seq_(n)` функции передаётся.

#### Результаты

[image: seq_range]
[image: seq_random]

Рисунки подтверждают, что `sorted_insertion()` показывает линейное поведение на отсортированном вводе (`seq_range`=0,1,2,3,4,...,`n-1`). И квадратичное на случайном вводе (`seq_random`). Коэффициент перед `log2(N)` показывает приближённо соответствующую степень в функции роста алгоритма в зависимости от размера ввода:

```
|------------------------------+-------------------|
| Fitting polynom              | Function          |
|------------------------------+-------------------|
| 1.00  log2(N)   +  1.25e-015 | N                 |
| 2.00  log2(N)   +  5.31e-018 | N*N               |
| 1.19  log2(N)   +      1.116 | N*log2(N)         |
| 1.37  log2(N)   +      2.232 | N*log2(N)*log2(N) |
```

## reporttime + pandas

Собрав результаты измерений времени выполнения функций сортировки из `daedra.py` (`sorted_*()`) для разных типов (уже отсортированный/случайный) и размеров ввода (длины от 1 до 100000):

```
import random
import daedra
from reporttime import get_functions_with_prefix, measure_func

times = {}  # (function name, input type, exp size) -> time it takes
for f in get_functions_with_prefix('sorted_', module=daedra):
    for N in range(6):
        for case, L in [
            ("range", list(range(10**N))),
            ("random", list(range(10**N)))]:
            if case == "random":
               random.shuffle(L)
            times[(f.__name__, case, N)] = measure_func(f, [L])
```

Удобно исследовать результаты интерактивно, используя `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([dict(function=f, input=i, size=10**n, time=t)
                   for (f,i,n), t in times.items()])
```

К примеру, чтобы сравнить поведение функций на уже отсортированном вводе:

```
def plot_input(input):
    p = df[df.input==input].pivot(index='function', columns='size', values='time')
    p.T.plot(loglog=True, style='-o', title=input)  # same style as in @MaxU's answer
    return p

plot_input('range')
```

[image: range input]

Поведение на случайном вводе:

```
plot_input('random')
```

[image: random input]

Или сравнить поведение одной функции для разных типов ввода на одном графике:

```
p = df[df.function=='sorted_insertion'].pivot(index='input', columns='size', values='time')
p.T.plot(loglog=True, style='-o', title='sorted_insertion')
```

[image: sorted_insertion function]

[соответствующий jupyter notebook](https://gist.github.com/zed/d096104959af0d31166749f8a5c14058).

Answer (score 5):

```
import numpy
from timeit import default_timer as timer


start_time = timer()

#
# <Описание функций selection, insertion и bubble>
#

def python_sort(array_to_sort):
    array_to_sort.sort()


number = 10000
ary = numpy.random.choice(number, number, replace=False)
print(len(ary), ary[:5])
print()


def my_time_this(function):
    items = numpy.copy(ary)

    t = timer()
    function(items)
    elapsed = timer() - t

    print_format = "{:<15} {:.10f} secs. number: {}, first 5: {}"
    print(print_format.format(function.__name__, elapsed, len(items), items[:5]))


my_time_this(python_sort)
my_time_this(selection)
my_time_this(insertion)
my_time_this(bubble)

print()
print("Total elapsed: {:g} secs".format(timer() - start_time))
```

Консоль:

```
10000 [2961 2787 7118  974 7860]

python_sort     0.0004201819 secs. number: 10000, first 5: [0 1 2 3 4]
selection       11.4002999229 secs. number: 10000, first 5: [0 1 2 3 4]
insertion       11.0592371948 secs. number: 10000, first 5: [0 1 2 3 4]
bubble          24.4177592050 secs. number: 10000, first 5: [0 1 2 3 4]

Total elapsed: 46.8791 secs
```

---

Перед каждой сортировкой делал копию массива, т.к. после первой сортировки массив стал бы отсортированным и это помешало бы адекватно оценить следующие алгоритмы сортировки

Answer (score 5):

При желании можно слегка автоматизировать и визуализировать процесы замера времени:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

def selection(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort.copy()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        idxMin = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
            if a[j] < a[idxMin]:
                idxMin = j
        tmp = a[idxMin]
        a[idxMin] = a[i]
        a[i] = tmp
    return a

def insertion(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort.copy()
    for i in range(len(a)):
        v = a[i]
        j = i
        while (a[j-1] > v) and (j > 0):
            a[j] = a[j-1]
            j = j - 1
        a[j] = v
    return a

def bubble(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort.copy()
    for i in range(len(a),0,-1):
        for j in range(1, i):
            if a[j-1] > a[j]:
                tmp = a[j-1]
                a[j-1] = a[j]
                a[j] = tmp
    return a

def np_sort(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort.copy()
    return np.sort(a)

def py_sorted(arrayToSort):
    a = arrayToSort.copy()
    return sorted(a)

res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=['selection', 'insertion', 'bubble', 'py_sorted', 'np_sort'],
    columns=np.logspace(2, 5, 4).astype(int),
    dtype=float
)

for j in res.columns:
    a = np.random.choice(j, j, replace=False)
    for i in res.index:
        stmt = '{}(a)'.format(i)
        setp = 'from __main__ import a, {}'.format(i)
        print('processing [{}]\tarray size: {}'.format(i,j), end='')
        res.at[i, j] = timeit.timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)
        print('\t\ttiming:\t{}'.format(res.at[i, j]))
print(res)

plt.figure()
ax = res.T.plot(loglog=True, style='-o', figsize=(10,8))
ax.set_xlabel('array size')
ax.set_ylabel('time (sec)')
plt.savefig('c:/temp/result.png')
```

Результаты:

```
             100       1000       10000        100000
selection  0.002741  0.271356  26.972909  2717.141041
insertion  0.002278  0.258578  26.933399  2644.332910
bubble     0.005418  0.566870  62.634945  5881.305021
py_sorted  0.000066  0.000689   0.008864     0.112469
np_sort    0.000298  0.000313   0.001023     0.012551
```

result.png:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `number=10` не ясно, что измеряет. Для стабильности, [можно `perf` модуль использовать (даже с тем же интерфейсом можно)](https://perf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html).

Comment: @jfs, параметр `number` можно легко поменять. Я использовал 10, чтобы не очень долго ждать результат. Суть данного ответа в автоматизации процесса замера времени...

Comment: @MaxU Немного не пойму к чему там тот шаг? за что он отвечает?

Comment: @daedra, если вы про цикл спрашиваете, то там как раз делаются все замеры и сохраняются результаты

Comment: меня смущает, что увеличение размера в 10 раз приводит у вас к уменьшению времени выполнения. Нельзя ожидать, что люди будут каждый параметр в коде на разумность проверять. Используйте те величины для `number`, которые по вашему имеют смысл в вашем примере.

Comment: @jfs, изменил, чтобы вас не смущать... ;)

Comment: @MaxU судя по графику `number=50` не помогло. Чтобы час не ждать результатов, можно использовать адаптивное значение для number, как в `reporttime.measure_func` из моего ответа (как это `python -mtimeit` команда делает).

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно замерить время работы нескольких функций:

```py
import time

def func1():
    ...

def func2():
    ...

tasks = [func1, func2]
for func in tasks:
    t = time.time()
    func()
    print(f"{func.__name__}: {time.time()-t}")
```