# Измерять время работы пользователя в программе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте! 
Мне нужно вымерять количество секунд затраченных пользователем на работу в моей программе. То есть при завершении работы программы выводить на экран сколько времени работал человек. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Примерно так, как на изображении.

Comment: в оболочке часто есть встроенная time команда, которая может выводить время и другие ресурсы потраченные процессом. [В тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775750/23044)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью модуля [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) можно добавить callback, который сработает при [закрытии скрипта "нормальным" способом](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/a2933e84aa64a4d30dbe4a798a98dd6d87a29b27/exit_handler.py). Если возникли ошибки, то или весь действующий код нужно обернуть в `try`/`catch`, либо использовать [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

```
import atexit
from timeit import default_timer as timer


start_time = timer()


def exit_handler():
    print('Execution time: {:.3f} secs.'.format(timer() - start_time))


atexit.register(exit_handler)

number = int(input('Input number: '))
print('My super sum:', sum(range(number ** 2)))
```

Консоль:

```
Input number: 100
My super sum: 49995000
Execution time: 1.841 secs.
```

---

Можно и через декораторы регистрировать, [например](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html#atexit-example):

```
import atexit

@atexit.register
def goodbye():
    print("You are now leaving the Python sector.")
```

---

**UPD.** заменил `time.clock` на `default_timer`, т.к. сейчас это [устаревший метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock).

Comment: можно упомянуть, что atexit срабатывает при "нормальном" завершении. И обработчиков может быть несколько которые неизвестное время могут выполняться. В качестве альтернативы, можно просто `try: main($ finally: log_end()`. В некоторых случаях может иметь смысл свои обработчики signal определить, чтобы время завершения записывать. Или внешнего наблюдателя использовать (вне процесса).