# Программа, реализующая алгоритм определения значения минимального элемента в матрице

Tags: python, numpy

Помогите, пожалуйста, с заданием. Есть код, но не знаю как замерить время выполнения

Задание: Написать программу, реализующую алгоритм определения значения минимального элемента в матрице с использованием list, замерить время выполнения и сравнить с готовой реализацией алгоритма из библиотеки NumPy.

```
import random
arr = []
x = int(input("размер = "))
for i in range(x):
    arr.append([])
    for j in range(x):
        arr[i].append(random.randint(1,10))
min = arr[0][0]
for i in range(x):
    print()
    for j in range(x):
        print(" ",arr[i][j],end = ' ')
for i in range(x):
    print()
    for j in range(x):
        if(arr[i][j] < min):
            min = arr[i][j]
print("минимальный =", min)
```

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(500, size=(500,500))
B=np.min(A)
print(B)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как можно засечь время выполнения каждой из функций и суммарное время выполнения программы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775089/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В jupyter-notebook где удобно работать с numpy  есть команда %%time, а так уже задавали вопрос здесь [[775089]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775089/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)