# Самый быстрый метод убрать повтор символов из строки с сохранением порядка

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, список, методы

У меня есть следующая переменная:

```
chars = "GG43SAaaAA2221gwjkVJa31d1g"
```

Мне нужно, чтобы из этой строки убрались повторы и сохранялся порядок символов

(Строчные и прописные буквы разные, а не одинаковые, поэтому **"A"** и **"a"** не одно и тоже)

Вот так:

```
chars = "G43SAa21gwjkVJd"
```

Какой метод **наибыстрейший?**, который будет быстрее всего убирать повторы и сохранять порядок символов в строке? python 3.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Могу предложить попробовать так:

```
chars = "GG43SAaaAA2221gwjkVJa31d1g"
res = "".join(dict.fromkeys(chars).keys())
```

res:

```
'G43SAa21gwjkVJd'
```

Comment: Мне бы желательно видеть, что он быстрее, чем другие. С 1 примером я к сожалению понять не смогу. Видел в интернете несколько вариантов, но незнаю, как проверить, что они быстрее, чем другие

Comment: Так у вас вопрос не в нахождении решения, а в тестировании скорости работы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/775089/235436

Comment: @Олёша: Дополню, т.к. обновляю в памяти `PEP8`. [В рекомендациях сказано](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): В критичных к времени выполнения частях программы используйте ''.join() — таким образом склеивание строк будет выполнено за линейное время независимо от реализации python.